# How to add a preference page?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I want to add a preference page in my RCP program, just like you see in the eclipse, when you click Windows->Preferences->General, a preference page appears in the right panel. But I'm not familiar about RCP, how can I add a option in the Windows->Preferences lists, and make it work like the "General" option?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

There are several tutorials out there:

1. http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Preferences/preferences.htm
2. http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipsePreferences/article.html

Comment: Thank you very much! The second one is especially useful to me.

Answer (score 1):

Open the plugin.xml from the Package explorer and go to Extensions tab. Click add and search for **org.eclipse.ui.preferencePage** and Finish. Right click on the preferncePage plugin, choose New-->Page. On the right hand side, fill the required fields and save it.
Run the plugin as an Eclipse application. Go to Windows-->Preferences and you will find your custom preference page.